# Change Activity Bar Icons, Make Background Transparent

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change the activity bar icons in Visual Studio Code? I kept googling but couldn't find anything, and have seen people do it, [here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4psPk.png).

Also, can I make VSC's background transparent?

Comment: they are the old style icons, If you want these you have to run an old version of VSC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of the badge, you need to add this to your `settings.json` file:
`File > Preferences > Settings > Open json file`

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBarBadge.background": "#0F99D677",
    "activityBarBadge.foreground": "#EEE"
},
```

In your example, looks it is a theme with a CSS gradient or a picture as background. It seems this cannot be achieved with a setting, you probably need an extension for this.

Same to make VS Code transparent; you could use this one:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=s-nlf-fh.glassit